# jquery ajax:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to submit form.And I want to receive validation errors of json，there is an error message in Chrome debugger's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('articles/') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
                    var span = '#formAticle span[id=span-' + key + ']';
                    $(span + '>strong').text(value);
                    $(span).parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".alert-success").prop("hidden", false);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            alert('The server failed somewhere');
        });
});
```

response json in Chrome debugger:

```
{
"title":["The title field is required."],
"content":["The content field is required."],
...
}
```

Comment: what is the array you are looping through?`

Comment: Wild guess:  data.responseJSON is undefined.

Comment: You're sure you shouldn't just be iterating over `data`, as there no such thing as `responseJSON`, unless you somehow created that property ?

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak  json  ```{
"title":["The title field is required."],
"content":["The content field is required."],
...
}```

Comment: @adeneo  what should I do?

Comment: ok,thanks ,I delete `.responseJSON`, it works!